# DataStax Devcenter: export data as JSON

Tags: json, cassandra, cql, datastax, datastax-enterprise

Using this DevCenter, how to save result of query to json (I actually get JSON table) to file on disk? I know there is "COPY All as CSV" when right click on any row, however I dont see copy as JSON. If I just use copy as csv, the original format is modified and therefore of no use for further access in any other tool.

In short, there should be some way to export as whatever type. But it seems this visual tool only has export as csv.

Comment: The CSV format is included in DevCenter for exporting data to be used with cqlsh or spreadsheets. What would you use the JSON for?

Comment: Well, I imagine you are familiar that JSON and CSV are different format. The data stored is in JSON format and therefore, I want to export as JSON. I think I mentioned this in question already.

Comment: I need JSON data to be used for modelling task. I guess answer should not depend on what I need data for. I just need data as in original format.

Comment: Cassandra doesn't have a JSON data type so most probably that data is stored like a string. You could select only that column and then use the copy as CSV as a workaround.

Comment: Hmm. Well, I actually have 3 columns. The two columns are normal, the third looks like JSONized. I try to select only that column and copy as CSV. But to further use that csv data, its uncomfortable because its neither original JSON nor straightforward to read, for e.g. in R (I am using to read different ids of that JSON column in R). But it does not look normal JSON.

Answer (score 1):

DevCenter 1.4 was recently released (Jul 20, '15) and has support for Cassandra 2.2 `INSERT JSON`, `SELECT JSON` statements and `fromJson` and `toJson` functions. Included in this support, DevCenter can display JSON for entire result sets or individual cell contents.

So with the combination of Cassandra 2.2 and DevCenter 1.4 you can query your data using either `SELECT JSON` or `toJson` (for a single column) and then copy/paste the JSON data as you wish.